# Is there a way to delete duplicate from a cell value (value of a given row and column) using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In my Postgres db, I have a table with some columns where one column `B` has values as follows:

```
A      B
a1     b0, b1, b1
a2     b2, b3
a3     b4, b4, b5, b5
```

My expected output should be like this:

```
A      B
a1     b0, b1
a2     b2, b3
a3     b4, b5
```

Is there a simple `UPDATE` postgresql to do this task?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350669/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `b` is an array:

```
UPDATE mytab
SET b = (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT x)
         FROM unnest(b) AS x);
```